# Kurento one-to-many broadcast with recording

Tags: kurento, kurento-media-server

I am following this tutorial:-
https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2many.html
for one to many broadcasting.

Now I need to add code to recording on server side. Any ideas how?

There is tutorial for recording:- https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/js/tutorial-recorder.html
but the "core kurento" code structure there is not the same as in "one2many" broadcasting tutorial.

Any help / ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In one to many, you must record only presenter webrtcendpoint

To implement that you need to

- add a new endpoint of recordingEndPoint

  ```
  pipeline.create('RecorderEndpoint', {uri: argv.file_uri}, function(error, recorderEndpoint)
  ```
- connect to the Webrtcendpoint of the presenter

https://github.com/ciberstrigo/kurento-nodejs-recording

```
 webRtcEndpoint.connect(recorderEndpoint, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        webRtcEndpoint.connect(webRtcEndpoint, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                return callback(error);
            }
              return callback(null);
        });
    });
```